# Add the "Select All" option after long tapping a UITextView

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitextview

When I long tap any text in the standard Mail app, I am presented with a "Select All" option.

[image]

However, when I long tap text in my own [UITextView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextView_Class/index.html), I do not get that option. How do I add it?

[image]

Here is the relevant code for my UITextView is set up:

```
self.messageLabel = [[UITextView alloc] init];
self.messageLabel.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeAll;
self.messageLabel.editable = NO;
self.messageLabel.scrollEnabled = NO;
self.messageLabel.selectable = YES;
self.messageLabel.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
self.messageLabel.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0.0;
```

Answer (score 10):

It's because of:

```
self.messageLabel.editable = NO;
```

So for fixing that you have three options.

#### Option 1

Remove that line (or set it to `YES`) and it'll show those options.

---

#### Option 2

Customize [UIMenuController](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UIMenuController_Class/index.html)

---

#### Option 3

Implement `canPerformAction:` method in your viewController class where you defined the `UITextView`

```
- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
{
    if (action == @selector(selectAll:))
    {
        return YES;
    }
    
    return [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
}
```

And implement the `selectAll:` method like:

```
- (void)selectAll:(id)sender
{
    [self.messageLabel selectAll:sender];
}
```

**NOTE:** If you didn't implemented the `canPerformAction:` then just defining `selectAll:` method will also work.

Comment: It appears that only defining `-(void)selectAll:(id)sender` in the view controller will add the "select all" feature. However, now the menu that pops up is broken. Neither tapping "copy", nor "select all", nor "define" will do anything - the menu does not dismiss itself. Additionally, I set a breakpoint inside the `selectAll` function and it never breaks there.

Comment: @Pwner: It's working in my sample app. I used the same code, I suspect there is something with the code. Can you explain a little bit, what you have changed now ?

Comment: I just defined selectAll: but it wasn't got called. Any idea why ?

Answer (score 2):

Subclass `UITextView` and override `canPerformAction:withSender:` will do the trick.

```
class TextView : UITextView {

    override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
        if action == #selector(selectAll) {
            if let range = selectedTextRange, range.start == beginningOfDocument, range.end == endOfDocument {
                return false // already selected all text
            }
            return !text.isEmpty
        }
        return super.canPerformAction(action, withSender: sender)
    }
}
```